# Having issues getting Image information into database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

When I submit my form I am able to pass the information for the articles into my database but the information for my Images does not send.

I'm using a transaction so I can insert information into 2 tables from 1 form.

This is the transaction that passes the information to the database:

```
$conn->query("START TRANSACTION");
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO articles(article_title, article_text, article_date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['article_name'], $_POST['description']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO images (article_id, image_caption, image_filename) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),?,?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['image_caption'], $_FILES['upload']['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->query("COMMIT");
```

Here is my form:

```
<form id="inputArticle" name="inputArticle" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<p> <label for="article_name">Article Title:</label> <input name="article_name" placeholder="Name of the article" id="article_name" type="text" size="50" maxlength="50" /> </p>
<p> <label for="description">Article Content:</label> <textarea name="description" placeholder="Content of the article"id="description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea> </p>
<p> <label for="image_filename">Choose File to Upload</label><br /> <input type="file" name="image_filename" id="image_filename" /> </p>
<p> <label for="image_caption">Image Caption:</label> <textarea name="image_caption"  id="image_caption" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea> </p>
<p> <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert New Article" /> </p>
</form>
```

**Side Note:**
When I remove the image upload code from the sql and the form, everything seems to work. the id and description are sent to the database, so I'm thinking the problem is with the image upload part.

Comment: Issent $_FILES['upload']['name'] supposed to be $_FILES['image_filename']['name'']

Comment: Thats it! I feel dumb now. Thanks Jonas

Comment: No problem :) Answer your own question and take the "solved" mark please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to change input name.

```
Issent $_FILES['upload']['name'] supposed to be $_FILES['image_filename']['name'']
```